# B&W grating with defined columns widths MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns, column-width

I'd like to create a fullscreen image with black and white grating. The columns of the grating have all the same width and I want to define them with mm.

Furthermore is it possible to have a variable that , depending on its value , offsets the first column by the defined value ? (e.g. if variable OFF= 0,25; then the first column will start 0,25mm distant from the beginning of the image).

Thank you in advance !

EDIT:

This is what i tried but I can only define the number of columns and not the exact width in mm.

```
nx = 500 ;
ny = 500 ;
A = zeros(nx,ny);
grating = nx/100;
i = 0 ;
C = grating;
D = 2*grating;
fac = D;
while i ~= nx;
    A(1:1:ny,C:1:D) = 1 ;
    C = C + fac;
    D = D + fac;
    i = i + fac;
end
imshow(A,'InitialMagnification','fit');
```

Comment: Show us some code; what have you tried?

Comment: What is your resolution in mm/pixel?

Comment: My laptop has 1366 X 768

Comment: @user2425899 Resolution is irrelevant.  We would need to know the exact size of each pixel on your screen if you accurately want to draw pixels to the mm.

Comment: @rayryeng How do I find it ?

Comment: @rayryeng do you have any idea on how i could do it ? :)

Comment: @rayryeng Hi :) i found out my exact pixel size. My new laptop resolution is 1920x1080 ( FHD ) and my screen width is 34,5 cm ( it s a 15,6" screen). So my pixel size is 34,5/1920 = 0,01796 cm which is 0,1796 mm.